# Use jackson to serialize everything in an Enum

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm looking for the simplest way to return the entire enum contents as json. So far I have

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum MyType {
  ENTRY("Entry")

  public final String value;
  
  MyType(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

then in my service:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String myTypes = Arrays.stream(MyType.values()).map(myType -> {
            try {
                return om.writeValueAsString(myType);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

this comes out fairly nicely as "{"value":"Entry"}"

But is there a way to do it automatically using annotations? Also how to wrap this in some label, so it comes out like "entries: {"value":"Entry"}"

Edit:
Ah, little better

```
java.util.HashMap map = new java.util.HashMap<String, MyType[]>();
map.put("entries", Arrays.asList(My.values()));
try {
    return om.writeValueAsString(map);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

}

Comment: Are you referring @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)  annotation here, not to be used?

Comment: What is exactly your use case? Why do you need this?